# Composer not loading specific files in sub-directories

Tags: php, composer-php

I have this autoload block in my main project `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "lib"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Within that project is the `lib` dir with some packages I've manually added which have their own `composer.json` files. So far, all the code from these packages loads correctly except for one helper file as seen in this `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/commands",
        "src/controllers",
        "src/events",
        "src/models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Example\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/Example/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

None of the functions in `src/Example/helpers.php` are usable from within the project.

How do I configure my autoloaders to work right for such a scenario?

Comment: If you use `classmap` (and I guess `files` too), you need to use `composer dump-autoload` everytime you add a new file.

Comment: @Marwelln didn't help. I tried that within each package sub-dir separately and also didn't help.